# activerecord-sqlserver-adapter .save! not returning an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

I am trying to determine why I am not able to obtain the ID of a model after it is saved to the database:

```
request.attributes = attributes
request.touch
request.save!
puts request.inspect
```

The console prints:

```
#<Request id: nil, ...>
```

using:

```
activerecord (4.2.9)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.2.18)
activesupport (4.2.9)
rails (4.2.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

you might try to reload model and inspect it again:

```
request.reload
puts request.last.inspect
```

though according to your code snippet the model must be persisted - `save!` would throw error otherwise.

P.S. I'd rather leave a comment on your question but don't have enough reputation.

Comment: It seems `reload` is expecting the request to have an id, which it doesn't seem to:

`in 'find_with_ids': Couldn't find Request without an ID (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)`

Comment: that means that model is not persisted. maybe for some weird reason logging is disabled in rails console and you just don't see the error, try to turn it on explicitly before saving request: `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::INFO`. though validation errors must be displayed in any case.

one more idea for debugging: check whether record is really inserted in database (say, in `rails dbconsole` or `psql` if you're using PostgreSQL). just to make sure that problem is on ActiveRecord side.